# Extra page while using simultaneously minitoc and float

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, minitoc

I have a problem for a while now: there is always an extra page at the end of my documents. I notice that this happens when I use simultaneously `minitoc` and `float`.

I track this issue down to this minimal code :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I can compile this without any error and it generates an empty page with page number 1. (I use TeX Live 2013 on Linux, and I happens both with LaTeX and pdfLaTeX).

How can I simultaneously create tables of content by chapter and use the `[H]` option in `\begin{figure}[H]` ?

Update after egreg answer: here is a new minimal example with some text, that creates always a new page.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\include{ch01}
\end{document}
```

You can put anything in `ch01.tex` and an extra page will be created.

Comment: If I add contents, I don't get additional pages.

Comment: You're right: same for me. Anyway, the minimal code should not give an empty page. Could you try to put some text in an external file and include it with a \include{} in the main document ? For me it generate an extra page.

Comment: Encountered the same problem and been looking for a solution for quite a while. Today I encountered another [StackExchange question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194295/minitoc-package-adds-extra-page-when-used-with-float-and-lastpage-packages "StackExchange question"), that is quite similar to this problem: The solution was posted by user [Werner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner), suggesting a bug in the minitoc hint-printing macro. When loading the minitoc package without hints, the additional page is not created. Load the minitoc package with the `[nohints]` Option: