# minitoc package adds extra page when used with float and lastpage packages

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, knitr, minitoc

The `minitoc` package adds extra page when used with `float` and `lastpage` packages. I figured out that this problem can be resolved by loading `minitoc` package before `float` and `lastpage` packages. In `LyX` the `float` package is loaded automatically and could not figure out how to force `LyX`  use `minitoc` package before loading `float` and `lastpage` packages. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\minitoc
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[1]
\section{Material \& Method}
\blindmathpaper
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\minitoc
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[1]
\section{Material \& Method}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

**Edited**

It is also working in `LyX 2.1.1` if I remove `\includepdf[pages={1},scale=1]{Back.pdf}` at the end of the document. However if I include `\includepdf[pages={1},scale=1]{Back.pdf}` at the end of the document it adds extra page. Any thoughts.

**Updated**

I've narrow downed the problem. My following MWE in `.Rnw` format adds extra page at the end of document when using `minitoc` package. Thanks again for your help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter}
\minitoc
\section{Introduction}
<< Test >>=
1:50
@ 
\blindtext[1]
\section{Material \& Method}
\blindmathpaper
\includepdf[pages={1},scale=1]{Back.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to my tests, it is enough to load `minitoc` before `lastpage` only (`float` can be loaded before of after), and since apparently LyX only loads `float`, then you shouldn't have any troubles; simply load `minitoc` *before* `lastpage`.

Comment: Thanks @GonzaloMedina for your interest in my problem. It adds an extra page at the end of the document.

Comment: Yes, but simply loading `minitoc` before `lastpage` solves it. Doesn't it?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, putting `minitoc` before `lastpage` solves the issue in `LaTeX` but not in `LyX`.

Comment: Why not? In your post, you mention that LyX loads `float` automatically, not `lastpage`, so `lastpage` should not be a problem.

Comment: Sorry @GonzaloMedina for any inconvenience. I don't why this is not working in `LyX 2.1.1`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: It is also working in `LyX 2.1.1` if I remove `\includepdf[pages={1},scale=1]{Back.pdf}`. However if I include `\includepdf[pages={1},scale=1]{Back.pdf}` it adds extra page. Any thoughts.

Comment: @MYaseen208 it is always useful for LyX questions if you post two MWEs, one that is the .lyx file (it is just a text file) and one that is the exported LaTeX.

Comment: Please @GonzaloMedina and scottkosty see my updates. Looking forward for your help.

Comment: Please @scottkosty see my updates. Looking forward to your help.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I do not see a .lyx file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, [`minitoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) provides the user with a number of `hints` (a package option). These hints are printed to the console or executed `\AtEndDocument`, and there's a spurious space somewhere in the definition of the hints-printing macro (a definite bug). In your particular example, the page `Back.pdf` is inserted *before* `\AtEndDocument`, causing the spurious space to insert an additional (unwanted) page, even though it has nothing on it.

To avoid this, call `minitoc` with the `nohints` package option:

```
\usepackage[nohints]{minitoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc
```

This empty-last-page problem is very specific to your usage, since the spurious space might otherwise go unnoticed at the end of a "regular" document.

Comment: (+1): Thanks @Werner for your helpful answer. Much appreciated.