# blank page after includeonly

Tags: pdftex, incompatibility, include

Following this [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427044/includeonly-and-page-numbering) regarding a conflict between `\includeonly` and the `hyperref` package, here is another problem I found with `\includeonly`.

With the following mwe,a first compilation `pdflatex main.tex` yields a full pdf where everything is fine. Though, after **uncommenting the line with \includeonly** a new run of `pdflatex main.tex` yields a pdf with an extra blank page...

**The issue is related to the use of either the minitoc or float package**.

I am aware of this [fix proposed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129065/blank-pages-after-include-in-latex-report-class) in an older post but it creates a [conflict with the hyperref package post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427044/includeonly-and-page-numbering).

Do you see any way around it ?

Here is **main.tex**:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minitoc}

% my choice of chapter
    %\includeonly{chapitre_1}

\begin{document}
    % plan de cours
        \include{description}
    % chapitre 1
        \include{chapitre_1}
        \include{chapitre_1_exercices}
    % chapitre 2
        % ...
\end{document}
```

and where **description.tex** is:

```
\newpage
\section*{Plan de cours pour la session d'}
Le cours \dots
```

**chapitre_1.tex** is:

```
\newpage
\section{Chapitre 1}

\label{chap_1}
% table des matières
\newpage
\subsection{Introduction}
    Contenu du chapitre\dots
\newpage
    page supplémentaire pour afficher les numéros de page
```

and **chapitre_1_exercices.tex** is:

```
\newpage        
\subsection{Exercices d'application}
    Liste d'exercices\dots
```

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{newclude}` to your preamble. (This was in the link you provided.)

Comment: This does not seem to change anything... I still get the extra blank page...

Comment: Even if you delete your .aux files?

Comment: @erik yes, I still have my extra blank page after deleting all the .aux files and recompiling...

Comment: Try without loading the `minitoc` package.

Comment: @erik indeed, it works fine without the minitoc package but the point of my post is to underline the conflict when minitoc (or float) is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alain It is minitoc producing hints causing an extra blank page. Load minitoc with `nohints` option. See,
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194377/231055